# Send Lync meeting Invitations using Exchange web service and UCWA

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, exchangewebservices, ucwa

I want to make a webservice which sends lync meeting invitations to attendees. I've done the UCWA Part, for generate the meeting conference adress.

But now i'm trying to create the invitation using EWS. I can send standard appointment, with the meeting URL as body, but the Outlook Lync addin dont recognize it as a lync meeting.

Thanks to the [Outlook Spy addin](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm), I can see the right tags for transform my appointment into a lync meeting. So I think that i just have to add the same tags than an original Lync meeting (created with the lync addin for outlook).

I've tried to set extended properties of my appointment:

```
Guid MY_PROPERTY_SET_GUID0 = Guid.NewGuid();
            Guid MY_PROPERTY_SET_GUID1 = Guid.NewGuid();
            Guid MY_PROPERTY_SET_GUID2 = Guid.NewGuid();
            Guid MY_PROPERTY_SET_GUID3 = Guid.NewGuid();
            Guid MY_PROPERTY_SET_GUID4 = Guid.NewGuid();
            Guid MY_PROPERTY_SET_GUID5 = Guid.NewGuid();
            Guid MY_PROPERTY_SET_GUID6 = Guid.NewGuid();
            Guid MY_PROPERTY_SET_GUID7 = Guid.NewGuid();

            ExtendedPropertyDefinition EPD0 = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(MY_PROPERTY_SET_GUID0, "MeetingType", MapiPropertyType.Long);
            ExtendedPropertyDefinition EPD1 = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(MY_PROPERTY_SET_GUID1, "OnlineMeetingConfLink", MapiPropertyType.String);
            ExtendedPropertyDefinition EPD2 = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(MY_PROPERTY_SET_GUID2, "UCMeetingSetting", MapiPropertyType.String);
            ExtendedPropertyDefinition EPD3 = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(MY_PROPERTY_SET_GUID3, "UCOpenedConferenceID", MapiPropertyType.String);
            ExtendedPropertyDefinition EPD5 = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(MY_PROPERTY_SET_GUID5, "UCMeetingSettingSent", MapiPropertyType.String);
            ExtendedPropertyDefinition EPD4 = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(MY_PROPERTY_SET_GUID4, "OnlineMeetingExternalLink", MapiPropertyType.String);
            ExtendedPropertyDefinition EPD6 = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(MY_PROPERTY_SET_GUID6, "UCInband", MapiPropertyType.String);
            ExtendedPropertyDefinition EPD7 = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(MY_PROPERTY_SET_GUID7, "UCCapabilities", MapiPropertyType.String);

            appointment.SetExtendedProperty(EPD0, 65536);
            appointment.SetExtendedProperty(EPD1, cd.HttpJoinLink);
            appointment.SetExtendedProperty(EPD2, cd.getUCMeetingSettings());
            appointment.SetExtendedProperty(EPD3, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            appointment.SetExtendedProperty(EPD4, cd.ConfJoinLink);
            appointment.SetExtendedProperty(EPD5, cd.getUCMeetingSettings());
            appointment.SetExtendedProperty(EPD6,[XMLVALUE]);
            appointment.SetExtendedProperty(EPD7, [XMLVALUE]);

             string mailAddress;
            foreach (string a in attendees)
            {
                if (a.StartsWith("sip:"))
                {
                    mailAddress = a.Substring(4, a.Length - 4);
                }
                else
                {
                    mailAddress = a;
                }
                appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add(mailAddress);
            }

             appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);
```

The two [XMLVALUES] are just copy/paste from outlook spy, this is a pretty long text that i don't write here for clarity purpose.

After that I recieve my invitation but, these tags doesn't appear as property tags in Outlookspy, so my appointment is not reconized as a "Lync meeting".

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider executing the *Lync Meeting* button on the ribbon in Outlook programmatically to get the right meeting item. The [ExecuteMso](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862419.aspx) method of the CommandBars class executes the control identified by the idMso parameter. This method is useful in cases where there is no object model for a particular command. Works on controls that are built-in buttons, toggleButtons and splitButtons. See [Office 2013 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798).

Answer (score -1):

**This what you need to make EWS meeting to online meeting.**

```
ExtendedPropertyDefinition extendedUCMeetingSetting = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(Guid.NewGuid(), "OnlineMeetingExternalLink",MapiPropertyType.String);
```

appointment.SetExtendedProperty(extendedUCMeetingSetting, skype_meeting_join_url)