# How to create Microsoft Teams calendar event through EWS APIs

Tags: microsoft-teams, exchangewebservices

I went through the documentation and understood that there are Graph API's to create a Microsoft Teams appointment.

e.g., isOnlineMeeting" property to true, and "onlineMeetingProvider" property to "teamsForBusiness".

Is there any way to use EWS web services to do the same?

Thanks & Regards,

Mahesh

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do what the Graph does when creating a Meeting in EWS (pretty much because the API itself pre dates Teams). You can create an online meeting using the onlinemeeting endpoint https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http then when you create the Meeting using EWS you set a number of extended properties manually and create the Body of the Message with the online meeting link manually using the information returned via the onlinemeeting link. If you have a hybrid setup where you have OnPrem and Online Mailboxes this is what you need to do for any OnPrem mailboxes eg this is what you had to do with skype for business [Send Lync meeting Invitations using Exchange web service and UCWA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28699610/send-lync-meeting-invitations-using-exchange-web-service-and-ucwa). If all your mailboxes are in the cloud the easy solution is don't use EWS use the Graph.